# Как работают атрибуты в PHP 8?

Tags: php, php8

В новой версии PHP(**PHP 8**) появилась возможность указывать [атрибуты](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/ru.php#attributes).

Пример в документации не понятен.
Прочитав статьи [тут](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-2-php-8-attributes) и [тут](https://stitcher.io/blog/attributes-in-php-8) яснее не стало. Как они работают и как их нужно использовать?

Comment: В который раз разработчики php оказываются заложниками своего убогого парсера, который не умеет различать контексты.

Comment: Это обычные аннотации. Их просто наконец-то вытащили из комментариев.

Comment: Что значит обычные аннотации? Приведите пример. `phpDoc` - аннотации? Указание типа аргуметна метода в `phpDoc` - аннотация?

Comment: Да, если phpdocumentor пожелает, сможет перенести всё в эти новые атрибуты.

Comment: Так что тогда есть аттрибуты?

Comment: Это специальная форма синтаксических метаданных, которая может быть добавлена в исходный код. [Атрибуты в Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_annotation)

Comment: Так это чистый `phpDoc`.  Вы не внесли ясности. Я вот в RFC вычитал, что это аналог декораторов в JS.

Comment: Декораторы, синтаксически - это тоже аннотации

Comment: Когда вы говорите phpdoc, вы, вероятно, подразумеваете не только аннотации средства для генерации документации, но и все остальные аннотации внутри комментариев `/** */`.  Благодаря новому синтаксису, теперь не нужно парсить эти комментарии(вручную или другими средствами, такими как doctrine/annotations) Вообще, вопрос хороший, надеюсь, кто-нибудь найдёт достаточно времени чтобы написать к нему достойный ответ =)